# How to effectively use tf.bucket_by_sequence_length in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, bucket

So I'm trying to use tf.bucket_by_sequence_length() from Tensorflow, but can not quite figure out how to make it work.

Basically, it should take sequences (of different lengths) as input and have buckets of sequences as output, but it does not seem to work this way.

From this discussion: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5609
I have the impression that it needs a queue in order to feed this function, sequence by sequence. It's not clear though.

Function's documentation can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/contrib.training/bucketing#bucket_by_sequence_length

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need input tensor to be a queue, which can be e.g. a  `tf.FIFOQueue().deque()`, or a `tf.TensorArray().read(tf.train.range_input_producer())`.

This notebook that explains it quite well:

https://github.com/wcarvalho/jupyter_notebooks/blob/ebe762436e2eea1dff34bbd034898b64e4465fe4/tf.bucket_by_sequence_length/bucketing%20practice.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

My following answer is based on Tensorflow2.0. I can see that you might be using an older version of Tensorflow. But if you happen to use the new version, you can effectively use the bucket_by_sequence_length API in the following manner.

```
# This will be used by bucket_by_sequence_length to batch them according to their length.
def _element_length_fn(x, y=None):
    return array_ops.shape(x)[0]


# These are the upper length boundaries for the buckets.
# Based on these boundaries, the sentences will be shifted to different buckets.
boundaries = [upper_boundary_for_batch] # Here you will have to define the upper boundaries for different buckets. You can have as many boundaries as you want. But make sure that the upper boundary contains the maximum length of the sentence that is in your dataset.

# These defines the batch sizes for different buckets.
# I am keeping the batch_size for each bucket same, but this can be changed based on more analysis.
# As per the documentation - batch size per bucket. Length should be len(bucket_boundaries) + 1.
# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/bucket_by_sequence_length
batch_sizes = [batch_size] * (len(boundaries) + 1)

# Bucket_by_sequence_length returns a dataset transformation function that has to be applied using dataset.apply.
# Here the important parameter is pad_to_bucket_boundary. If this is set to true then, the sentences will be padded to
# the bucket boundaries provided. If set to False, it will pad the sentences to the maximum length found in the batch.
# Default value for padding is 0, so we do not need to supply anything extra here.
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(_element_length_fn, boundaries,
                                                                       batch_sizes,
                                                                       drop_remainder=True,
                                                                       pad_to_bucket_boundary=True))
```